# Return Response 201 Created in controller. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, response

How to return a response `201 - Created`

I know this solution.

```
public function store(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    return response()->noContent(201);
});
```

But it's quite long.

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: This is really not "quite long" IMO. By the way, you can use `abort(201);` but it's not a good approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use magic numbers

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

...

public function store(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    return response()->noContent(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
});
```

Comment: Well. Sound good. 
But still, I would rather see.
`response()->created();`

Comment: I said 'Would rather see'. 
I just wanted to know a short way.

Answer (score 5):

The `ResponseFactory` is macroable. You can add custom functions to it if you would like:

```
\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::macro('created', function () {
    return $this->noContent(201);
});
```

Then you can call it on the `ResponseFactory`:

```
return response()->created();
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Responses - Response Macros](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#response-macros) `macro`